# A simple script. A simple binding. So why isn't it simple?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I've used `xbindkeys` to associate a hot-key with `/usr/bin/test.sh`

I can run the script two ways now! (well, not always! hence this question.)

eg. `/usr/bin/test.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit
```

- Using terminal ... `gedit` launches
- Using hot-key  ... `gedit` launches

---

However, when `test.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/sh  
nautilus
```

- Using terminal ... `nautilus` launches
- Using hot-key  ... `nautilus` ***fails to execute!***

---

My bash skills are basic, to say the least... Is there some bracket, or quotes thing I need here?... or is there something inately differnt between "nautilus" and "gedit"... is it "xbindkeys"? ... I'm stuck :(

Comment: Do any messages appear in `.xsession-errors` in your home directory when `test.sh` produces no visible effect?

Comment: Gilles: I'll check .xsession-errors soon... but now I want to mention that `nautilus` is the only **offender** ... `xclip` is fine; I was expecting it to behave like a Windows CLI utility I used for years... but **nautilus** is still an issue.. I'll check the log as you suggest..  (I've ammended my question to refer only to **nautilus**)

Comment: If you change the script to start `notnautilus`, does a message like `notnautilus: command not found` appear in `~/.xsession-errors` (it should)? What if you start `nautilus --no-desktop`? What about `nautilus /tmp`?

Comment: Gilles: I just now saw your message... I managed to work it out, but you were spot on.. I wish I'd noticed it earlier ;) ... I tried adding just the path (more detail below)... WE got there.. Thanks to all... and now I need a  coffeeeeeee!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/nautilus ~/
```

Perhaps your hot-key manager isn't aware of your PATH.

Comment: A good thought, but unfortunateley it didn't work... same result...  I wonder if it is a permissions thing: **-rwxr-xrwx**, but I think that means read/write/execute for all and sundry!...

Comment: @fred.bear It is not the permission issue. Usually 755 works fine. I should warn you though that you shouldn't set the 'write' permission for 'others' like you do on the file. Correct it with `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/test.sh`.

Comment: How about just specifying `nautilus` for the hot key? Also, what's your hot-key manager? I use xbindkey and compiz command plugin. Both don't exhibit any of the problem you are having.

Comment: UPDATE: The only **offender** is `nautilus` (see comment attatched to question)

Comment: Gödel: Thanks..I was (partially) aware of the security issue of the write permission, and perhaps a bit more aware now.. Does a script **owned** by root, but executed by a non-sudo'd user have any elevated rights?  (... too many years of windows nonchalance)....    I am using `xbindkeys-config` to set up the bindings ... I haven't used Compiz Commands yet.... And I have tried `nautilus` directly into *xbindkeys*, but it doesn't work there either.

Comment: **Whoo-Hoo!!**... I've got it!... From the terminal CLI, from Alt+F2, from `alacarte`, a command of just `nautilus` is **enough**... but it seems that for `xbindkeys` it needs a PATH... eg `nautilus ~/` ... so Gödel, you were on the right track..... but I have no idea why it behaves differntly for different launchpads, but I'd better leave "well enough" alone :)  ... This myth is busted!

Comment: @fred.bear Congrats :) About your question, if the file is owned by root and the user executing it is non-root who is not a member of the group that the file belongs to, then you are assumed to be a stranger and will only have the permission of the last three column of -rwxr-xrwx in your case, i.e. 'rwx' (read, write, execute). If this is case, anybody on your system can change (write) the content of the file, which is why it is dangerous to leave it as it is.

Comment: Please update the answer that has been marked with the actual anwser and not the question. Housekeeping!

Comment: PS. as it turned out the **only** hard-coded path that was needed is the directory which nautilus opens up to. The full *working* command is now:  **`nautilus ~/`**

Answer (score 1):

<s>You need to add exec and the path of the executable as Gödel mentioned. For example:</s>

`exec /usr/bin/gedit` .

I just tried doing the same with GNOME's own keyboard shortcuts, surprisingly I seem to have the same problem. Have you tried this yourself?

Update: it seems that this is only happening with some keyboard shortcuts. I tried Super+G and it didn't work, but CTRL+G for grun works perfectly. Can you see if the same works for you? Maybe it's that another shortcut should work.

Comment: Roland, that didn't change things... I have 8 hotkeys set by `xbindkeys`, but the 2 I've mentioned just don't respond... The script(s) run via the terminal... Also, when I put the command directly into `xbindkeys`, rather than a script, it still won't work... (a mystery)

Comment: UPDATE: The only **offender** is `nautilus` (see comment attatched to question)

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort... Different keys don't apply in my case, because the **xbindkeys** inteface has a **test-the-command** button, and it doesn't work from there either.. (in case you haven't already seen my comment (see Gödel): my particular problem with nautilus has been resolved...  ### I tried **Super+g** and **Ctrl+g** for `grun`... They both work.  (aren't computers such fun ;) ... never a dull moment!